# Can't shorten the height of this li tag

Tags: css

Although this seems like simple CSS, I can't seem to shorten the height of the `li`s highlighted here:

[image]

I've tried adding in a `line-height`, `height`, making sure the paddings and margins are 0...yet no dice. What is creating the space above and below the text? It's not the `a` tag within the `li`. Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Paste your relevant code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two `line-height` settings in your CSS that you need to take care of:

1) style.css (line 251)

```
#primary-menu ul{
    line-height: 33px;
}
```

2) style.css (line 204)

```
#primary-menu ul a{
    font: bold 12px/33px 'Merriweather', serif;
}
```

Comment: Ah, it was that second line-height I didn't see. Thank you.